# List objects in a specific folder on Amazon S3

Tags: php, sdk, amazon-s3

I am trying to get the list of `Object` under a specific folder in my bucket.

I know that to get a list of all of my objects I do:

```
    $objects = $client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket
));
```

I want to get only the objects under the folder `my/folder/test`. I have tried adding

```
        'key' => "my/folder/test",
```

And

```
        'prefix' => "my/folder/test",
```

But it simply returns all of the objects in my bucket.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You need to use `Prefix` to restrict the search to a specific directory (a common prefix).

```
$objects = $client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
    "Bucket" => $bucket,
    "Prefix" => "your-folder/"
));
```

Comment: Its case sensitive, so it must be 'Prefix' where I wrote 'prefix'. :\ Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is it possible to modify this to only list the buckets within a bucket (1-level deep)?

Comment: @raphael75 for that you can find [`s3.listBuckets()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-buckets.html) method

Comment: I am getting a Generator instance, how can I access the data?

Answer (score 39):

The answer is above however i figured i would supply a complete working example that can be copied and pasted directly into a php file and ran

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

require_once('PATH_TO_API/aws-autoloader.php');

$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => 'YOUR_KEY',
    'secret' => 'YOUR_SECRET',
    'region' => 'us-west-2'
));

$bucket = 'YOUR_BUCKET_NAME';

$objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
    "Bucket" => $bucket,
    "Prefix" => 'some_folder/' //must have the trailing forward slash "/"
));

foreach ($objects as $object) {
    echo $object['Key'] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: S3Client::factory is deprecated in SDK 3.x, otherwise the solution is valid

Comment: for replacement of the factory method, use this,
$s3Client = new S3Client([
            'version' => '2006-03-01',
            'region'  => 'ap-southeast-1',
            'credentials' => [
                'key' => 'yourkey',
                'secret' => 'yoursecreky'
            ]
        ]);

Answer (score 2):

"S3Client::factory is deprecated in SDK 3.x, otherwise the solution is valid" said by RADU

Here is the updated solution to help others who come across this answer:

```
# composer dependencies
require '/vendor/aws-autoloader.php';
//AWS access info  DEFINE command makes your Key and Secret more secure
if (!defined('awsAccessKey')) define('awsAccessKey', 'ACCESS_KEY_HERE');///  <- put in your key instead of ACCESS_KEY_HERE
if (!defined('awsSecretKey')) define('awsSecretKey', 'SECRET_KEY_HERE');///  <- put in your secret instead of SECRET_KEY_HERE


use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$config = [
    's3-access' => [
        'key' => awsAccessKey,
        'secret' => awsSecretKey,
        'bucket' => 'bucket',
        'region' => 'us-east-1', // 'US East (N. Virginia)' is 'us-east-1', research this because if you use the wrong one it won't work!
        'version' => 'latest',
        'acl' => 'public-read',
        'private-acl' => 'private'
    ]
];

# initializing s3
$s3 = Aws\S3\S3Client::factory([
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => $config['s3-access']['key'],
        'secret' => $config['s3-access']['secret']
    ],
    'version' => $config['s3-access']['version'],
    'region' => $config['s3-access']['region']
]);
$bucket = 'bucket';

$objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
    "Bucket" => $bucket,
    "Prefix" => 'filename' //must have the trailing forward slash for folders "folder/" or just type the beginning of a filename "pict" to list all of them like pict1, pict2, etc.
));

foreach ($objects as $object) {
    echo $object['Key'] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Never use access and secret keys plain in the code, use `Aws\Credentials\CredentialProvider::defaultProvider()` for a secure approach.