# Listing objects filtered by prefix in AWS with PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I recently got the task to manage data which is stored via the Amazone Web Service.

According to the docu of Amazone i tried the following code to list all Objects within a bucket and it works fine:

```
$aws = Aws::factory('/path/to/my/config.php');

$s3 = $aws->get('s3');

$it = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array (
        'Bucket' => 'myBucket',
    )
);

foreach($it as $o){
    echo $o['Key']."<br />";
}
```

But i need to list all objects only with a certain prefix. To achieve this i added the following line below line 6 of the shown code:

```
        'prefix' => 'myPrefix/',
```

(The actual key of the file i want to access is (scheme):
myPrefix/subPrefix/subPrefix2/file.txt)

But the code keeps returning **all** objects in the bucket.
I havn't found any helpfull hints in the Amazon docu for my question.

Can anyone tell me (one of) the correct syntax to list all objects of a given prefix in PHP?

thank you in advance for any help

Comment: If you have large number of objects I wouldn't recommend using this approach. Track objects stored via some database and search that database instead. You can leverage `S3 Notifications` and `SNS` to track objects created in your bucket.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'll definitly check this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the following thread ...

[List objects in a specific folder on Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683206/list-objects-in-a-specific-folder-on-amazon-s3)

... you need capitalized the index-values of the array that is passed as second argument to the getIterator-function:

'**P**refix' => 'myPrefix/',