# How to write the path of a sub folder in a bucket in s3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a bucket called `music` in AWS S3 and I have a sub-folder within it called `15`. I can reach this folder on the GUI however using the PHP SDK if I put the folder path of the sub folder 15 as `music/15` I get an error. How do I write the path to a sub-folder within the bucket `music`?

The code below should help:

```
private function get_flist() {
    try {
        $result = $this->s3->getIterator('ListObjects', [
            'Bucket'    => $this->bucketmp3,
            'EncodingType'  => 'url'
        ]);
        return $result;
    } catch (Aws\Exception\S3Exception $e) {
        echo "There was an error getting list of files.\n";
        print_r($e);
        return null; // error
    }
}
```

Note: `bucketmp3=music/15`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List objects in a specific folder on Amazon S3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683206/list-objects-in-a-specific-folder-on-amazon-s3)

Comment: what is the `Exception` you are getting?